# How to get a Apex report (IR) column value in javascript function?

Tags: oracle-apex

Using Apex 4.2.1

Actually I have a Apex (IR) report and want to create a javascript function where user can see message if two report columns date are not matched. for example, in report I have column date1 and date2 so date1 can not be less than date2. so I have create a link and when click on link then popop window should comeup (javascript) message box where function compare those two dates. so i m struggling how to get report column values in javascript function.

Thx.

Comment: Do you really want to use JavaScript? I think there may be more simple solutions available. Perhaps you can remove the link, and add a new column to the report that uses a CASE statement to compare the two dates. Or if you really want a popup, perhaps make the popup display a simple apex page which compares the values using PL/SQL. A JavaScript workaround is probably possible, but it will require more work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of click-popup solution you could use the Highlight and Compute features of IR:

1. Add a computed column X representing a result of comparison to your report. `Actions->Format->Compute`, use `DECODE` or `CASE` expressions to return 1 when date1 is lesser than date2.
2. Highlight report rows with X=1. `Actions->Format->Highlight`, select a condition and a color.
3. Optionally hide the computed column. `Actions->Select Columns`.
4. Save report as default. `Actions->Save Report->Save As Default Report Settings`.

If you steel want to check column values by JS, use Dynamic Action for report region on After Refresh event. For example, next code goes through rows of IR based on `DEPT` table and alerts `DNAME` and `LOC` columns:

```
var $dnames = $( 'td[headers=DNAME]', this.triggeringElement );

$( 'td[headers=LOC]', this.triggeringElement ).each( function( indx, El ) {
  alert( $( El ).html() + " - " + $dnames.eq( indx ).html( ) );
} )
```

As you can see, I use report column aliases to filter cells.